# Slowly changing dimension type 2 implementation in SSIS

Tags: ssis, scd

what is the best way to implement the type 2 dimension in SSIS from the following options:

1.using merge statement.
2.using SSIS SCD component
3.using lookup, conditional split(custom way to implement it).

could you please give me the detail on it how to implement all of these and pros and cons of each.

thanks in advance.
Zaim raza.

Answer (score 1):

4) [Dimension Merge SCD](http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/)

Even if you don't go with that component, watch the 6 part videos linked from that page and see which one works best for your workload and skill-set.